# BeautifulSoup selectors fail to match arbitary tags?

Tags: python, css, beautifulsoup

I want to get the tags with `data-a` attribute. The selector I believed was correct returns a blank list.

How do I successfully select with CSS selectors the tags with `data-a`?

```
In [53]: s = BeautifulSoup("<div data-a='12'></div>")

In [54]: s
Out[54]: <html><body><div data-a="12"></div></body></html>


In [55]: s.select('div')
Out[55]: [<div data-a="12"></div>]

In [56]: s.select('[data-a]')
Out[56]: []
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known limitation in the BeautifulSoup CSS selector implementation; it'll only match attribute names with *letters, digits and underscores*, not dashes. See [issue #1304007](https://bugs.launchpad.net/beautifulsoup/+bug/1304007).

You can still select those elements with a `find_all()` call:

```
>>> s.find_all(**{'data-a': True})
[<div data-a="12"></div>]
```

The `**{..}` applies arbitrary keyword arguments; `data-a` is not a valid Python identifier so we need to use a work-around there. `True` means *any element with this attribute*.

You could patch the code to accept dashes in attribute names too:

```
import re
from bs4 import PageElement

PageElement.attribselect_re = re.compile(
    r'^(?P<tag>\w+)?\[(?P<attribute>[\w-]+)(?P<operator>[=~\|\^\$\*]?)' +
    r'=?"?(?P<value>[^\]"]*)"?\]$'
    )
```

With the updated expression matching attributes with dashes works:

```
>>> import re
>>> from bs4 import PageElement
>>> s.select('[data-a]')
[]
>>> PageElement.attribselect_re = re.compile(
...     r'^(?P<tag>\w+)?\[(?P<attribute>[\w-]+)(?P<operator>[=~\|\^\$\*]?)' +
...     r'=?"?(?P<value>[^\]"]*)"?\]$'
...     )
>>> s.select('[data-a]')
[<div data-a="12"></div>]
```